# How to conditionally install a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-services

I've got two similar Windows Services in my service executable. The value of one of the settings in the shared configuration file determines whether both Windows Services will be installed or just one will be installed.

In the shared configuration file, there's a setting called `Enabled`. If this is set to true, then both Windows Services should be installed. If it's set to false, then only the first Windows Service should be installed.

My project installer uses a conditional to check the `Enabled` setting when installing and it appears to be working well...as I only see the first Windows Service when it's set to false and see both when it's set to true.

And, if the `Enabled` setting is set to true and both Windows Services are installed, they both appear to be working well when I start them up. However, when the `Enabled` setting is set to false and only the first Windows Service is installed, I'm unable to start the first (and only) Windows Service.

Here's the error message I receive:

```
Windows could not start the Service1 service on Local Computer.

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Here's my ProjectInstaller:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;

    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller1;

    private ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller2;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }        
}
```

Here's my InitializeComponent() method from the ProjectInstaller.Designer:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    Assembly service = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ProjectInstaller));
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(service.Location);
    Installer[] installerArray = null;
    InstallerCollection installers = base.Installers;

    components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

    this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
    this.serviceInstaller1 = new ServiceInstaller();
    this.serviceInstaller2 = null;

    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;

    this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = "Service1";
    this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "Service1";

    if (config.AppSettings.Settings["Enable"].Value.Equals("true"))
    {
        this.serviceInstaller2 = new ServiceInstaller();
        this.serviceInstaller2.DisplayName = "Service2";
        this.serviceInstaller2.ServiceName = "Service2";
        installerArray = new Installer[] { this.serviceProcessInstaller1, this.serviceInstaller1, this.serviceInstaller2 };
    }
    else
    {
        installerArray = new Installer[] { this.serviceProcessInstaller1, this.serviceInstaller1 };
    }

    installers.AddRange(installerArray);
}
```

And here's the code from Program:

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new Service1(),
        new Service2()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

The problem seems to be in the ServiceBase since there are two services that are being run, but I'm not sure how to only start the first one if the second one isn't installed.

I thought that I could check to see if the service was installed and change the code in Program to the following, but I still received the error:

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

    ServiceController serviceController = ServiceController.GetServices().FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceName == "Service2");

    if (serviceController != null)
    {
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1(),
            new Service2()
            };
        }
    else
    {
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        }; 
    }

    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the way you're installing or starting up the service should be a problem.  My best guess is that there's an unintentional dependency on Service2 inside Service1's constructor or OnStart() function.  Try creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll likely be able to work out the problem yourself; if not, post the MCVE and someone will probably be able to help.

Comment: Both services have a FileSystemWatcher and when I don't enable or install Service2, the Event Log says there's an ArgumentException with the FileSystemWatcher..ctor in Service2. This leads me to believe that Service2 is running, but I was trying to avoid that with the conditional ProjectInstaller.

Comment: In the first version of Main() you're constructing a Service2 object, but the OnStart() method shouldn't be called unless service2 is installed.  If you're creating the FileSystemWatcher in the constructor, you shouldn't; move all initialization to OnStart.  The second version of Main() probably doesn't do what you were expecting, now that I look at it more closely, because I don't think you can call GetServices() during service startup.  But I don't think it is necessary for Main() to know whether service2 is installed or not.

Comment: If in doubt, you can double-check whether service2 is installed using the Services administrative tool or the `sc query` command.

Comment: For your first comment, that's the problem. When I install the service, Service1 shows up, but Service2 doesn't. For your second comment, the FileSystemWatcher was being created in the constructor, but even after moving it to the OnStart method, Service1 still wouldn't start (and Service2 doesn't show up in the Services tool or sc query). The constructor for Service2 now only has InitializeComponent() and another method that intializes some variables from the config file.

Comment: I tinkered with it some more and cleaned up the code to dispose of the FileSystemWatcher properly and I got it to work. Oh the joy of modifying someone else's code, especially when they don't document it. Anyway, if you'll post your comment about putting the FileSystemWatcher in the constructor, I'll mark it as the answer since it put me on the right path. And thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to hear you sorted it out.  It would be preferable for you to post an answer explaining exactly what the problem was and how you fixed it.  Or if you're not sure exactly which change(s) made it work, we could close it as "can no longer be reproduced".